# Functions in MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Is it generally better to run functions on the webserver, or in the database?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO example (hash) VALUE (MD5('hello'))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO example (hash) VALUE ('5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592')
```

Ok so that's a really trivial example, but for scalability when a site grows to multiple websites or database servers, where is it best to "do the work"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I try to think of the database as the place to persist stuff only, and put all abstraction code elsewhere. Database expressions are complex enough already without adding functions to them.

Also, the query optimizer will trip over any expressions with functions if you should ever end up wanting to do something like "SELECT .... WHERE MD5(xxx) = ... "

And database functions aren't very portable in general.

Answer (score 3):

I try to use functions in my scripting language whenever calculations like that are required. I keep my SQL function useage down to a minimum, for a number of reasons.

The primary reason is that my one SQL database is responsible for hosting multiple websites. If the SQL server were to get bogged down with requests from one site, it would adversely affect the rest. This is even more important to consider if you are working on a shared server for example, although in this case you have little control over what the other users are doing.

The secondary reason is that I like my SQL code to be as portable as possible. I don't even want to *try* to count the different flavors of SQL that exist, so I try to keep functions (especially non-standard extensions) out of my SQL code, except for things like SUM or MIN/MAX.

I guess what I'm saying is, SQL is designed to store and retrieve data, and it should be kept to that purpose. Use your serving language of choice to perform any calculations beforehand, and keep your SQL code portable.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I try to keep the database as simple (to the minimum) with Insert, Update, Delete without having too much function that can be used in code. Stored Proc is the same, contain only task that are very close to persistence data and not business logic related.

I would put the MD5 outside. This will let met have this "data manipulation" outside the storage scope of the database.

But, your example is quite "easy" and I do not think it's bad to have it inside...

Answer (score 2):

Use your database as means of persisting and mantaining data integrity. And leave business logic outside of it.

If you put business logic, any of it, in your database, you are making it more complex to manage and mantain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the time, you're going to want to leave the data manipulation to the webserver but, if you want to process databases with regards to tables, relations, etc., then go for the DB.

I'm personally lobbying my company to upgrade our MySQL server to 5.0 so that I can start taking advantage of procedures (which is killing a couple of sites we administer).

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers so far, I prefer to keep all the business logic in one place.  Namely, my application language.  (More specifically, in the object model, if one is present, but not all code is OO.)

However, if you look around StackOverflow for (my)sql-tagged questions about whether to use inline SQL or stored procedures, you'll find that most of the people responding to those are strongly in favor of using stored procs whenever and whereever possible, even for the most trivial queries.  You may want to check out some of those questions to see some of the arguments favoring the other approach.